# Convergence of a multivariable improper integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

> For which values of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the following integral converges?
>
> $\iint_D{\frac{1}{(\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)})^{5a}}}dxdy$
>
> $D=\{(x,y):\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1\}$

**My attempt:**

Changing to polar coordinates we have:

$2\pi\int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\frac{r}{(1-r^2)^{5a/2}}dr$

And then I don't know how to solve it... any suggestion would be nice.

---

My english isn't very good; if you find any errors, please correct them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good start.  You can evaluate the integral over $r$ using a $u$-substitution.  If $u=1-r^2$, then $du=-2rdr$ and the integral becomes
$$\lim_{n\to 0+}-\pi \int_1^n\frac{du}{u^{5a/2}}=\lim_{n\to 0^+}\pi \int_n^1\frac{du}{u^{5a/2}}$$
For which values of $a$ does this integral converge?

Comment: Thanks! the integral converges iff $5a/2<1$ iff $a<2/5$. One question, why the interval of integration becomes between 1 and n? If I evaluate $u(0) = 1$ but $u(1-1/n)$ is not $n$.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit cavalier with changing notation.  You had this $\lim_{n\to\infty}2\pi\int_0^{1-1/n}junk\, dr$.  It's a little cleaner if you just take a one sided limit and write this as $\lim_{n\to 1^-}2\pi\int_0^{n}junk\,dr$.  Then as $n\to 1^-$, $u$ goes to $0$ from the right.